# Is MTA responsible for wrapping lines

Tags: email

Are MTAs responsible for wrapping long header fielders and mail bodies?

Put differently, can the MUA be a complete asshole (example below) and leave it to the MTA to wrap messages to multiple lines as necessary to deliver the message to its final destination?

```
To: (1000 recipients on a single line)
Subject: (Complete transcript of "Eddie Murphy RAW" on a single line)

(The King James Bible on a single line.)
```

Answer (score 4):

No; the absolute limit is 998 characters, and the recommended limit is 78 characters. This comes from the current standard for email messages, [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). In section 2.1.1, "Line Length Limits", it states:

> There are two limits that this specification places on the number of
> characters in a line.  Each line of characters MUST be no more than
> 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding
> the CRLF.

However, MUA:s **should** be able to display messages properly even if the lines are longer than recommended. In the same section:

> it is incumbent upon implementations that display
> messages to handle an arbitrarily large number of characters in a
> line (certainly at least up to the 998 character limit) for the sake
> of robustness.

Comment: Yes; I’d add that the onus is on MSAs to enforce message format (see [RFC 4409 section 8](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4409#section-8)). It *is* however expected that headers may be folded at any point ([RFC 2822 section 2.2.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-2.2.3)).